# My Custom Skin won't Change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a skin by using Skincraft and I exported it to minecraft.net. I chose my skin and uploaded it. At the top it says,

> "Your skin has been changed! Please wait a few seconds for it to
>   update."

I went to Minecraft, clicked singleplayer and chose a random world at the top. I looked at my character, but it's still default. Multiplayer won't load for some reason. I don't know what I've done wrong!

Answer (score 11):

Here are eight possible reasons why your skin isn't showing:

1. Your skin has not refreshed yet. (If you're playing Minecraft 1.7 or above)
2. You never had a skin prior to the UUID update, which changes the way skins are stored (If you're playing any versions prior to 1.7)
3. You're not using a legal version of Minecraft, and therefore - Your skin isn't registered to your account.
4. The server you're playing on has `online-mode=false`. (Set to offline mode; no authentication)
5. You changed your `char.png` file within the minecraft.jar and not uploaded it to your minecraft profile.
6. You've uploaded it to your http://minecraft.net profile, but it's the WRONG dimensions (bigger than 64x64 pixels)
7. You're playing in offline mode.
8. None of youse have an internet connection.
9. You may have a bad internet connection and thus timed out or received incomplete information.

---

For #1, you'll just have to wait, and/or restart your game.
For #2, there's nothing you can do.
For #3, buy the game!
For #4, you should consider playing on servers that only allow 'premium'/paid users.
For #5, you should probabally log into http://minecraft.net.
For #6, you'll have to scale it down. Sorry :/ Unless you get the [HD skins mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1280351-forge-smp-ssp-hd-player-skins-capes).

For #7, go online!!! (Same goes for your brothers)
For #8, you'll need to be connected to the internet in order to retrieve skins.
For #9, nothing I can say apart from the generic "get better *internet*" or "clear off your bandwidth by downloading/uploading less (ie. Stop watching YouTube on 4K whilst others are gaming)".

Very likely, based on the information you've stated that your problem is #3.

Comment: On the possible reason #4, he's playing with lan. So that is not possible.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP. I am also playing on LAN. None of these listed reasons seem to be the cause.

Comment: My problem is none of the above. I can see my skin, but my friends can't...

Answer (score 7):

Skins can take time to do the initial trickle down. We (myself and the people I play with on a daily basis) have seen it take over an hour for everyone, including the person in question, to see the updated skin (people could see my Dr Who skin about 20min and 2 relogs before I could!!! Was frustrating :)).

You have done the steps correctly from what you stated in your post. As long as it said the upload is successful, all you should have to do now is wait.

Comment: I'm sorry. My eyes went straight to the words "Dr Who skin". More details, please.

Comment: I've been waiting for it to change for like 2 weeks!!

Comment: @user49947 It sounds like you did everything necessary, and need to contact Mojang for support.

Comment: no kidding and it's ok

Comment: @user49947 Wow, 2 weeks. Yeah that is time to contact Mojang directly. I have never had it take longer than a day for everyone to be on the same page. It usually only takes an hour at most.

Comment: @user49947 Before you contact Mojang, try to download it from skincraft and manually upload it to Minecraft.net. It may easily be a problem on skincraft's end, not Mojang's.

Comment: Yes can confirm this answer, personally. It can take up a full 2 days for the server to finally upload your skin.

Comment: @user49947 I'd suggest re-uploading it as well as contacting Mojang.  Sometimes your skin just doesn't load properly and you need to re-apply it.  This is especially true if you tried adding it before/after an update.

Answer (score 5):

Are you completely positive you restarted your Minecraft or opened a new launcher? In order to see your custom skin, you must successfully exit and restart your whole Minecraft.

Minecraft skins occasionally take a lot of time to upload and change; just be patient or check later by restarting.

Sometimes, the Minecraft Skin server is simply down or not working - check the status of all servers [here](http://help.mojang.com)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it just needs time to upload - usually from 1 - 20 minutes so just wait. You could try all logging off then logging back on after a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can see your own name on the tab screen (press tab while in game), if this isn't the case, try to relog. Also make sure to have a stable connection to the server. You can also always try to re-upload your skin image to minecraft.net.