# Why is my minecraft skin is not showing up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

Just like a normal Minecraft player, I go onto servers and play with friends.
But wait. When I join, my skin does not show up.

I am on a 1.8 server and nobody can see my skins.
Please help someone.

Comment: Some servers still use pre-UUID authentication, not letting skins work on a client. I know McPVP has this problem. Try using 1.7.2 - 1.7.5.

Comment: Hello @aloisius_vincent, welcome to arqade. Unfortunatly your answer has already been answered somewhere else. Therefor i've voted to close this question. If you have a specific problem thats not mentioned in the other question feel free to edit this question or ask about that specific situation.

Answer (score 3):

**I'm not going to bother writing a new answer for this:**
I literally copy-pasted my answer from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/188112/75275)

(With the exception of the strike-through on reasons that does not apply for this version of MC; 1.8)

---

> Here are eight possible reasons why your skin isn't showing:
>
> 1. Your skin has not refreshed yet.
> 2. <s>You never had a skin prior to the UUID update, which changes the way skins are stored (If you're playing any versions prior to 1.7)</s>
> 3. You're not using a legal version of Minecraft, and therefore - Your skin isn't registered to your account.
> 4. The server you're playing on has `online-mode=false`. (Set to offline mode; no authentication)
> 5. You changed your `char.png` file within the minecraft.jar and not uploaded it to your minecraft profile.
> 6. You've uploaded it to your http://minecraft.net profile, but it's the WRONG dimensions (bigger than 64x64 pixels)
> 7. You're playing in offline mode.
> 8. None of you have an internet connection.

>

> ---
>
> For #1, you'll just have to wait.
>   <s>For #2, there's nothing you can do.</s>
>   For #3, buy the game!
>   For #4, you should consider playing on servers that only allow 'premium'/paid users.
>   For #5, you should probabally log into http://minecraft.net.
>   For #6, you'll have to scale it down. Sorry :/ Unless you get the [HD skins mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1280351-forge-smp-ssp-hd-player-skins-capes).
>   
>   For #7, go online!!! (Same goes for your brothers)
>   For #8, you'll need to be connected to the internet in order to retrieve skins.

Comment: @Jordan Koontz 'youse' is a word, and it's spelt correctly. It is used as 'you' directed at multiple people because he mentioned playing as a group.